# D3 spacing between arcs

Tags: d3.js

I am pretty new to D3 chart and I created my first donut chart using D3, but I was wondering if there is anyway I can put some padding/spacing between each arc.

I know I could reduce each arc's start and end angles, for example,

arc 1: from 90degree to 120degree
arc 2: from 120degree to 150degree

reduce the angles above like
arc 1: from 92degree to 118degree
arc 2: from 122 degree to 148degree
and so on..

but I am curious if there is any easier way to put some spacing.

Here's my code and you can see the full code in JSfiddle.

```
var vis = d3.select(elementSelector);
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(svgInnerRadius)
.outerRadius(svgOuterRadius)
.startAngle(function(d){return anglePercentage(d[0]);})
.endAngle(function(d){return anglePercentage(d[1]);});
...

http://jsfiddle.net/24FaQ/
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: how did that work out?

Answer (score 17):

This is actually what you're looking for:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/f098d146315be4d1db52

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .padAngle(.02);
```

Comment: A pie is not an arc, and this will not work for arc layout

Answer (score 6):

If you're drawing on top of a solid background (white or otherwise), you can add stroke to achieve this effect without modifying the angles.

Here's a [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcj9r/).

```
vis.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d){return color(d[2]);})
    .attr('stroke', '#fff') // <-- THIS
    .attr('stroke-width', '6') // <-- THIS
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + svgWidth / 2 + ", " + svgHeight / 2 + ")");
```

This applies the stroke to all the edges, including the curved ones. If you need to avoid that, the you have to instead draw and position `line`s with white strokes at the start/end of each slice.

Comment: hi, i am looking for something same, is it possible if we provide space between to particular arcs. what i need to do is divide my graph in two parts(left and right)

Comment: One cannot simply use `stroke` instead of gap.